# Element scroll is not working to load more data from db

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this code for loading some data using a vertical scrolling on the element but it's not working if I change the **'div[data-tk="or"] .data .datadivmain'** to **document** it's working but I want to use elements scroll.
any thought on this?

```
  $('div[data-tk="or"] .data .datadivmain').scroll(function(e) {
            // grab the scroll amount and the window height
            var scrollAmount = $('div[data-tk="or"] .data .datadivmain').scrollTop();
            console.log('scroll position amount:', scrollAmount);

    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
    var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;
    if (scrollPercent > 30) {
        var main_data = $('div[data-tk="or"] .data .datadivmain');
        $(new_data).children().appendTo(main_data);
        $(Dahlia.V.currentPage.main + " .nex a").click();
    }

});
```

Comment: did you try $('address-here').bind("scroll", function(){ /* code here */  });

Comment: or did you try $('address-here').on("scroll", function () { /* code here */  });

Comment: I already tried this Top-Master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was with loading codes although I have added that inside the document ready it still was not working so I used the `setTimeout` function and it's working now.

```
setTimeout(function() {
        var new_data = $('div[data-tk="ro"] .data .datadiv');
        new_data.css('display', 'none');
        $('div[data-tk="ro"] .data .pagination ,div[data-tk="ro"] .data .listcount').css('display', 'none');
        var datadivmain = $("<div></div>").addClass("datadivmain");
        datadivmain.css({ 'overflow-y': 'auto', 'height': '500px' });

    if (!$('div[data-tk="ro"] .data .datadivmain').length > 0) {
        datadivmain.insertBefore(new_data);
        var main_data = $('div[data-tk="ro"] .data .datadivmain');
        $(new_data).children().appendTo(main_data);
    }
    $('div[data-tk="ro"] .data .datadivmain').scroll(function() {
        var main_data = $('div[data-tk="ro"] .data .datadivmain');
        // grab the scroll amount and the window height
        var scrollAmount = main_data.scrollTop();
        var documentHeight = main_data.height();
        var full_height = main_data[0].scrollHeight;
        // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
        var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / (full_height - documentHeight)) * 100;
        // console.log('full_height', scrollPercent);
        if (scrollPercent > 96) {
            $(new_data).children().appendTo(main_data);
            $(Dahlia.V.currentPage.main + " .nex a").click();
        }

    });
}, 1000);
```